# Visual Studio Code does not include C header files

Tags: c, visual-studio-code

I recently downloaded Visual Studio Code to begin learning the C programming language. I installed the program as well as the C extension. However, when I tried to create the "Hello, World!" program, it would not run, and in the Problems menu it did not recognize the stdio.h header file, saying that I need to update my includePath. I have not been able to find any stdio.h file on my computer to link to. Do I need to download the C library files (even though I have read they should be included with the compiler), and if so, where can I find them? Or is there another solution? Thanks, and sorry if this is a stupid question, I am new to this.

Comment: Did you do #include <stdio.h>? If you do #include "stdio.h" it doesn't work other than that no idea.

Comment: Yes, I did use the #include<stdio.h> command, and the problem is named to that line of the code.

Comment: Visual Studio **Code** does not come with a compiler.

Answer (score 1):

I think you might be confusing [VS Code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Studio_Code) with the [VS IDE](https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/).

VS Code is a source editor only; that is to say that it's basically just a glorified text editor. It has the ability to load extensions and open a shell to compile the code, and there are a few extensions that let you debug the code itself, but they can be tricky to get setup and installed to work well with C/C++ code. VS Code does *not* have a compiler/assembler/linker nor the requisite headers or SDK's as that is up to you (the user) to install and then point to those in your settings file.

The Visual Studio IDE, on the other hand, is a complete [integrated development environment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment) that also includes the system headers and SDK's for Windows, as well as the binaries to properly compile, link and assemble your code into a binary for a Windows system (cross platform is possible as well). The Visual Studio IDE comes in many different flavors with the latest being VS 2017.

If you wish to stick with VS Code, you'll need to grab a compiler and the appropriate header files for the system you're targeting. If you wish to just stick with Windows for now, you can grab the [Windows 7 SDK here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8279) or the [Windows 10 SDK here](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-10-sdk) .. you could even grab both and just reference the one you wish when you want. Note that the Windows 7 SDK includes the Microsoft C/C++ compiler, alternatively you can download the MSVC compiler from their [Build Tools](https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/#build-tools-for-visual-studio-2017) site.

There's also [Cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/) in which you can use the [GNU compiler](https://gcc.gnu.org/), and of course [Clang](https://clang.llvm.org/get_started.html), which can be referenced in both VS Code and the VS IDE.

I hope that can help.